# Why this $class works and $this->class not?

Tags: php, class, oop, instance

I have 2 classes

```
class A {

   // Do some stuff here!

}
```

and

```
class B {

   public $class = 'A';

   public function getClass(){

      //Case 1
      $class = $this->class;
      return new $class(); //work

      //Case 2
      return new $this->class(); //NOT work
      //or to be precise something like this
      return new {$this->class}(); 

   }

   // Do some other stuff here!

}
```

Why passing the class property to a var work and accessing directly NOT, like you see in the class above, **Case 1** vs. **Case 2** ?

Comment: Beacuse `return new $this->class();` is ambiguous.... do you mean `return new ($this->class());` or do you mean `return new ($this)->class();`? (brackets added to show the potential ambiguities)

Comment: Just FYI: The exact code above worked in my Linux server with PHP 5.6.21 perfectly.

Comment: it works for me as you were expecting with php 5.6 and 7

Comment: Placing the braces in your statement (as per your edit) `return new {$this->class}();` eliminates the ambiguity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is

```
$class = $this->class;
return new $class();
```

Here `$class` will contain the value "A". So it will get class "A" when you call new `$class()`

But in

```
return new $this->class();
```

It will search for a function `class()` inside the class "B". So it will not work.

**`$this` is for represent the current class instance. `$this -> something()` will always check for a function `something()` in the same class**

Answer (score 0):

Yes the reason is your doing it wrong,

This is how you will do it,

```
class A {

  public $class = 'A';

  function __construct() {
    # code...
  }

  public function getClass(){
    return $this;
  }

  public function instance () {
    return $this->class;
  }
}
```

To get the object/A

```
$obj = new A();
$new_obj = $obj->getClass();
```

To get the value of instance/$class,

```
$inst = $obj->instance();
```

`$this` refer to the class itself,

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me, if I remove **'()'** :).

```
return new $this->class; //Work just fine without parentheses
```

*Note: I use PHP 5.4.16*